# How to get string with special characters with accent from a configparser config.ini file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, python-unicode, configparser

I have some strings stored in a config.ini file which I extract with the configparser module.

My strings have some special characters:

**config.ini**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
instagram_subject=êtes-vous intéressé?
instagram_msg=êtes-vous intéressé?
```

I saved this file in the notepad with the type 'utf8'.

In my code which extract these strings, I get some weird output.

**Code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
insta_mail_message = config['Instagram']['instagram_msg']
insta_mail_subject = config['Instagram']['instagram_subject']
print(f"insta_mail_message : {insta_mail_message}")
print(f"insta_mail_subject : {insta_mail_subject}")
```

**Output**

```
insta_mail_message : Ãªtes-vous intÃ©ressÃ©?
insta_mail_subject : Ãªtes-vous intÃ©ressÃ©?
```

So Itried it all:
to decode, to encode, to decode and encode..... It just doesn't want to display my characters with accents!

Can someone tell me how to handle special characters from strings from a configparser file please?

Answer (score 3):

[Configparser.read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) accepts an encoding argument that defines the encoding to be used when reading the config file:

```
config.read('config.ini', encoding='utf-8')
```